# Socket.io only emitting to current user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm testing Socket.io in a basic app, but `io.sockets.emit` does not seem to be working as expected. Below is my relevant server-side code, Angular socket service, and controller. When I run this code only the current connection sees the console.log statement. Based on `io.sockets.emit` I would have expected the opposite (every OTHER user sees the message logged upon connection of another user).

server.js:

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var port           = process.env.PORT || 8000;
var io             = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  io.sockets.emit('connect', {data: 'hey there!'});
});

console.log('Connected on port ' + port);
exports = module.exports = app;
```

socket.service.js:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('socketService', function ($rootScope) {
    var socket = io.connect();
    return {
      on: function (eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function () {  
          var args = arguments;
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          });
        });
      },
      emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
          var args = arguments;
          $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            if (callback) {
              callback.apply(socket, args);
            }
          });
        })
      }
    };
  });
```

main.controller.js:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('MainController', MainController);

MainController.$inject = ['socketService'];

function MainController(socketService) {

    var vm = this;

    socketService.on('connect', function(data) {
        console.log('connection identified');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `connect` is a socket.io event that gets fired upon successful connection

Instead try using this on the server

```
io.sockets.emit('connect message', {data: 'hey there!'});
```

and this on the client

```
socketService.on('connect message', function(data) {
    console.log('connection identified');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Pays off to use specific event titles so you're not conflicting with 'reserved' words. I should have realized 'connect' would be used for something already.